# Confusion about Keras RNN Input shape requirement

Tags: keras, lstm

I have read plenty of posts for this point. They are inconsistent with each other and every answer seems to have a different explanation so I thought to ask based on my analyzing of all of them.

As Keras [RNN](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) documentation states, the **input shape** is always in this form `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. I am a bit confused about that but I guess, not sure though, that `input_dim` is always 1 while `timesteps` depends on your problem (could be the data dimension as well). Is that roughly correct?

The reason for this question is that I always get an error when trying to change the value of `input_dim` to be my dataset dimension (as input_dim sounds like that!!), so I made an assumption that `input_dim` represent the shape of the input vector to LSTM at a time. Am I wrong again?

```
C = C.reshape((C.shape[0], C.shape[1], 1))
tr_C, ts_C, tr_r, ts_r = train_test_split(C, r, train_size=.8)
batch_size = 1000

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(8, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, C.shape[1], 1), stateful=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

print('Training...')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(tr_C, tr_r,
          batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1,
          shuffle=True, validation_data=(ts_C, ts_r))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is not clear, if you have source code and actual error messages you should include them in your question. Just saying you have an error is not enough.

Comment: As Matias suggested, please show us the relevant code you have that throws such error, so we can help you better instead of asking.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you. Post is updated

Comment: @Kris can you add also the error you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, `input_dim` is the shape of the input vector at a time. In other words, `input_dim` is the number of the input `features`.

It's not necessarily 1, though. If you're working with more than one var, it can be any number.

Suppose you have 10 sequences, each sequence has 200 time steps, and you're measuring just a temperature. Then you have one feature:

- `input_shape = (200,1)` -- notice that the batch size (number of sequences) is ignored here
- `batch_input_shape = (10,200,1)` -- only in specific cases, like `stateful = True`, you will need a batch input shape.

Now suppose you're measuring not only temperature, but also pressure and volume. Now you've got three input features:

- `input_shape = (200,3)`
- `batch_input_shape = (10,200,3)`

In other words, the first dimension is the number of different sequences. The second is the length of the sequence (how many measures along time). And the last is how many vars at each time.

Comment: Neat! Thank you VERY much. Speaking of the length of the sequence, is it reasonable to be set as **the number of features of each sequence**? In my problem, each sample (sequence) contains 64 features which are forming a matrix of 10K rows and 64 columns!

Comment: Is it one time series? I'd say it's `(1, 10k, 64)`. The "time" is the central dimension. The "features" are independent vars. I assume you're mearusing these 64 vars each time, right?

Comment: Yes, as I said, my dataset is pretty much like any ordinary dataset. It has 10K samples each of 64 features. I thought to treat each sample as a sequence and then feed them to the RNN. That's all. BTW, `(1, 10k, 64)` does not work. It is working as `(10K, 64, 1)`