# Input 0 of layer "lstm_3" is incompatible with the layer, what is missing out?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a dataset with 69 features and 225700 rows and I tried to run a LSTM model using the code below but I keep getting this error message `Input 0 of layer "lstm_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 68)`. Please are there some things that I am not getting right?

```
DF = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\44759\All_Autoencoder_Data.csv")
DF1 = DF.drop('Labels', axis=1) # droping the Label feature

# Define input sequence shape
input_seq_shape = (DF1.shape[1], 1)

input_seq_shape
Out[8]:  (68, 1)

# Define LSTM autoencoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_seq_shape)
encoded = LSTM(68, activation='relu')(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = LSTM(5, activation='relu')(encoded)

decoded = RepeatVector(DF1.shape[1])(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(5, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(68, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = LSTM(1, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True)(decoded)
```

When I run the model above, the error message below keep popping up

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cf499e4225da> in <module>
      2 inputs = Input(shape=input_seq_shape)
      3 encoded = LSTM(68, activation='relu')(inputs)
----> 4 encoded = LSTM(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
      5 encoded = LSTM(5, activation='relu')(encoded)
      6 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\rnn\base_rnn.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    554 
    555         if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 556             return super().__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    557 
    558         # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    230             ndim = shape.rank
    231             if ndim != spec.ndim:
--> 232                 raise ValueError(
    233                     f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    234                     "is incompatible with the layer: "

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 68)
```

Comment: What is the sequence shape? What is the last dim1 in the shape?

Answer (score 0):

When running an `LSTM` (or any `recurrent`) model, both `fit()` and `predict()` expect the input data to be of shape `(batch_size, sequence_size, num_features)`.

If you want to run the model on a single sequence, you can do the following:

`input = np.expand_dims(input, axis=0)`

Read through some answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268608/confusion-about-keras-rnn-input-shape-requirement) for detailed explanations.

Comment: thanks for your response. However, I've tried it and it is still not working as the same error keeps coming up.

Comment: Try following the docs for rnns https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn

Comment: Here's the latest error **ValueError: Input 0 of layer "lstm_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 225702, 9, 68)**

Comment: Please update the code. What are the dims of the features and the length of a sequence?

Comment: here's the shape of the dataframe ```DF1.shape``` ```Output[10]:     (225711,  68)```. The ```sample, time_step, num_features``` I used was ```(225711, 9, 68)```.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stack LSTM layers, you need to set `return_sequences=True`, because you need to return the whole output, not just the last output.
For example:

```
encoded = LSTM(68, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
encoded = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(encoded)
...
```

With this, the output will have the shape of `(batch_size, sequence_size, num_features)`.
If you don't add `return_sequences=True`, the output shape will be just `(batch_size, num_features)`.

Comment: I've done that but still getting the same error

Comment: The code:
input_seq_shape = (68, 1)  
inputs = Input(shape=input_seq_shape)  
encoded = LSTM(68, return_sequences=True)(inputs)  
encoded = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(encoded)  
encoded = LSTM(5)(encoded)  
decoded = RepeatVector(input_seq_shape[0])(encoded)  
decoded = LSTM(5, return_sequences=True)(decoded)  
decoded = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(decoded)  
decoded = LSTM(68, return_sequences=True)(decoded)  
decoded = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(decoded)  
works. I recomend you not use "relu" in this case.

Comment: Your approach did not show the recurring error however, when I fitted the model ```model.fit()``` the loss has remained negative.

Comment: It depents on what kind of data you have and what loss you are applying. And I don't know that.